ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' when installing Python for SQL Server 2022
I have SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition installed on Win11.
Following the procedure at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install-sql-2022?view=sql-server-ver16,

An installer could not be found for Python 3.10 (deprecated).

I downloaded and installed Python 3.11 and 3.13 for windows but both presented the same error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

This error occurred when the following command from an elevated command prompt was executed:
python -m pip install -t "C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages" dill numpy==1.22.0 pandas patsy python-dateutil  

What's the solution to use Python in SQL Server 2022?

Where are you seeing the error message about an installer for Python 3.10? The URL that the Microsoft Learn article points to, https://www.python.org/downloads/, lists a Python 3.10.x download link (which still works). Also, "I downloaded and installed Python 3.11 and 3.13 for windows" Why are you downloading different versions of Python than the Microsoft Learn article instructs? You should be installing Python 3.10.x

If you can't find an installer for Python 3.10 and couldn't successfully install newer versions of Python, either, then I'm confused how you found yourself in a position to run Python pip from the command line. Shouldn't you be making sure your installation is successful before trying to use Python?

The link to python.org/downloads DOES work but no binary installer can be found.  It's all articles and reports of bug fixes.

I don't know what you mean by "but everything no binary installer can be found. It's all articles and reports of bug fixes". On the python.org/downloads page, click this link to go to the download page for that version. Then scroll down to the "Files" section and download either the .tgz or .xz zipped installer, whichever you prefer.

Also, the issue is not installing Python, but configuring it to run on SQL Server.  I tried newer versions of Python because the library in question 'disutils' was deprecated.  So it was an attempt to see if a newer version of Python would work.

You can also find a version of Python 3.10 packaged with the Microsoft Store here https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9pjpw5ldxlz5
